# solve the reccurence $\ T(n) = T(n-5) + \log n $

Tags: runtime-analysis

I tried to solve the following recurrence:

$\ T(n) = T(n-5) + \log(n) $ and $\ T(5) = 1 $

using iterative substitution:

$$\ T(n) = T(n-5) + \log(n) = \\T(n-10) + \log(n) + \log(n-5) = \\ T(n-15) + \log(n) + \log(n-5) + \log(n-10) $$

and so eventually I get for $\ i$ iterations: $$\ T(n) = T(n-5i) + \sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n}{5}-1} \log(n-5k) $$

Then what would be the $\ O $ of this function?

Comment: Notice that the recurrence only defines $T$ for the values of $n$ that are multiples of $5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $n = 5 m$.

Then by repeated substitutions you get

$$
\begin{align}
T(n) &= T(5m) = T(5) + \log(10) + \dots + \log(5m)\\ 
     &= 1 + \sum_{k=2}^m \log(5k) = 1 + \sum_{k=2}^m \left(\log{5} + \log{k}\right)\\
     &= 1 + (m-1)\log 5 + \sum_{k=1}^m \log k \\
     &= 1 + (m-1)\log 5 + O(m \log m) = O(n \log n)
\end{align}
$$
To evaluate the sum of logarithm, the Stirling Formula was used. E.g. look at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/385599/38034

Answer (score 1):

As only multiples of $5$ are involved, we set $n=5m$ and rewrite the recurrence as

$$P(m)=P(m-1)+\log5m$$ with $P(1)=1$. Then obviously

$$P(m)=1-\log5+\sum_{k=1}^m\log5k=1-\log5+m\log5+\log m!$$ or

$$T(n)=1-\log5+\frac n5\log5+\log\frac n5!=O(n\log n).$$